# Amazon S3 token generation from a Golang REST API

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm writing a Golang REST API that needs to generate S3 tokens for users so that they can upload files to the specific folder inside a bucket.

This is what I need to implement:

```
Method: GET
Endpoint: myapp.com/images/:imageid/token
Description: Return 2 tokens so that the user can upload files to the S3 
             bucket related to the image ID parameter.
```

I'm using the Golang echo framework.
And I'm not really sure how to implement this functionality.

Should this be done via the AWS SDK or does Amazon offer other ways of programmatically generrating tokens?

Comment: What kind of tokens are you trying to generate? It sounds like (since you say 2 tokens) you might be trying to generate short lived AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY pairs?

Comment: To be honest I don't know what the tokens should be. I think you're spot on. How would I generate these access keys from inside the program?

Comment: Pre-signed URLs then would be your go-to. You'd need to return one for each upload being performed. To be clear - short lived key pairs as mentioned in my first comment are _not_ where you want to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate tokens for users to upload files directly to s3, you can use [pre-signed URLS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html).

After generating a pre-signed URL, return that to the user and the calling application can use that to upload the file.

This example from the link above should be about what you're looking for:

```
svc := s3.New(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-west-2")}))
req, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("myBucket"),
    Key:    aws.String("myKey"),
})
str, err := req.Presign(15 * time.Minute)

log.Println("The URL is:", str, " err:", err)
```

Comment: This is great, Thank you.